# Linq: help me to make this work

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have this column:

```
    PersonId   CategoryId   SubCategoryId
1      61           47          
2      61           48          
3      61           0           424
4      61           0           425
5      84           55          
6      61                       585
7      101          48          
8      101                      424
8      666          47          
10     666                      424
```

When i search only for categoryId its fine, and subCategoryId its fine, but when i search for both, like categoryId = 47 && subCategoryId = 424. 
I cant make it work... in this case i only need person 61 and person 666.

i can do with a foreach, but not a good idea for performance.

u guys can help me?

```
if (ids.IdCategory != null && ids.IdSubCategory != null)
{
    query = unitOfWork.PersonSkillsRepository.GetAll().Where(m => m.IdCategory == ids.IdCategory || m.IdSubCategory == ids.IdSubCategory);
}
else if (ids.IdCategory != null)
    query = unitOfWork.PersonSkillsRepository.GetAll().Where(m => m.IdCategory == ids.IdCategory);
else
    query = unitOfWork.PersonSkillsRepository.GetAll().Where(m => m.IdSubCategory == ids.IdSubCategory);
```

first case i get half what i want... but i want some way to filter, because in this way i get 101 too and i dont know how to see if people have both category and subcategory

and i cant see a way to do this without a foreach

Comment: Please provide some code of what you tried.

Comment: Linq is as performant as your foreach-loop, when you don't mess around so much. Internally it iterates over the IEnumerable aswell.

Comment: There are a lot of websites which work this way - you give some requirements, and someone implements those requirements for you (probably for some money). But StackOverflow works in different way - you **try** to implement requirements on your own, and if you have some problems (error or unexpected results), then you give **problem description**, your current **code** and ask people to help you.

Comment: That is because there is no match row in your example for `categoryId = 47 && subCategoryId = 424`

Comment: i edit my post.

Comment: But a breakpoint on the first line, and let us know the value of `ids.IdCategory` and `ids.IdSubCategory`.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy i tried, and i have problems, put some code i give problem description and i ask for help... anything more?

Comment: @mjwills will give me lines 1,3,8,9,10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should group all person skills by person id, and then select only those groups, which contain both given category and sub category:

```
unitOfWork.PersonSkillsRepository.GetAll()
          .GroupBy(p => p.PersonId)
          .Where(g => g.Any(p => p.IdCategory == ids.IdCategory) 
                   && g.Any(p => p.IdSubCategory == ids.IdSubCategory))
          .Select(g => g.Key)
```

For optimization, you can filter out skills which do not match any of given categories before grouping.

```
unitOfWork.PersonSkillsRepository.GetAll()
          .Where(p => p.IdCategory == ids.IdCategory 
                   || p.IdSubCategory == ids.IdSubCategory)
          .GroupBy(p => p.PersonId)
          .Where(g => g.Any(p => p.IdCategory == ids.IdCategory) 
                   && g.Any(p => p.IdSubCategory == ids.IdSubCategory))
          .Select(g => g.Key)
```

Comment: Since this question is marked as Entity-Framework the "optimization" will probably only complicate the query generated, and not give any performance gain.

Comment: @Magnus depends of `GetAll()` return type. Usually it's an `IEnumerable<TEntity>` already fetched from database. Filtering out  most of records before grouping will speed up grouping and save some memory, also checking `g.Any` is O(N) which will increase with big group size

Comment: getall return type IQueryable

Comment: If it is `IQueryable` the "optimization" will give no performance gain (might even do the opposite). But for IEnumerable I agree with your statement.

Comment: @AntonioHenrique yes, in case of `IQueryable` use first version as @Magnus suggested. But keep in mind, that exposing `IQueryable` usually spreads data-access logic over application and tends for code duplication (same queries in different places)

Answer (score 0):

```
entities.Where(z => z.categoryId == 47 || z.subCategoryId == 424)
    .GroupBy(z => z.personId)
    .Where(z => z.Count() == 2)
    .SelectMany(z => z.ToList());
```

will likely get you the data that you need.

That query says 'filter the data and only return those where `categoryId` is 47 **or** `subCategoryId` = 424'. Then it groups them together and checks that there are two of them (i.e. one row for the `categoryId` and one for the `subCategoryId`).

Comment: i do that, this way 101 come too, i want both requeriment

Comment: yes, that my problem man... i trying a way to 101 not come too, filter in some kind, group... i dont know

Comment: What if one row has both 47 and 424, then it wont be included in this query.

Comment: That is true @Magnus . Based on his sample data that doesn't seem to be a likely scenario, but thanks for raising it.

Comment: @Magnus yeah.... It was like this before, but this change its not mine.. its from my boss

Answer (score 0):

[I just Showed the data of yours in Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03nUC.png)

The issue is that you don't have any value against CategoryId=47 in column SubCategoryId thats why when you search both of them together it gives nothing.
Try it by adding any value in SubCategoryId against CategoryId=47...

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

After the question is more clarified the following code should work

```
        if (ids.IdCategory != null && ids.IdSubCategory != null)
        {
            query = unitOfWork.PersonSkillsRepository.GetAll().Where(m => (m.IdCategory == ids.IdCategory || m.IdSubCategory == ids.IdSubCategory) && m.IdPerson != 101);
        }
```

Firstly your data will return null for your search criteria. Following are some example of linq that might help this scenario.

You can do different kind of linq.

```
    List<CollectionObject> ColObj = CollectionObject.GetListCollectionObj();

    List<CollectionObject> LinqResult = ColObj.Where(x => x.CategoryID == 47 && x.SubcategoryID == null).ToList();
```

The following code works fine with the linq statements above.

```
    class CollectionObject
    {
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public int? CategoryID { get; set; }
        public int? SubcategoryID { get; set; }

    public static List<CollectionObject> GetListCollectionObj()
    {
        List<CollectionObject> LColObj = new List<CollectionObject>();

        LColObj.Add(new CollectionObject() { PersonID = 61, CategoryID = 47, SubcategoryID = null });
        LColObj.Add(new CollectionObject() { PersonID = 61, CategoryID = 48, SubcategoryID = null });
        LColObj.Add(new CollectionObject() { PersonID = 61, CategoryID = 0, SubcategoryID = 424 });
        LColObj.Add(new CollectionObject() { PersonID = 61, CategoryID = 0, SubcategoryID = 425 });
        LColObj.Add(new CollectionObject() { PersonID = 101, CategoryID = 48, SubcategoryID = null });
        LColObj.Add(new CollectionObject() { PersonID = 101, CategoryID = null, SubcategoryID = 424 });
        LColObj.Add(new CollectionObject() { PersonID = 666, CategoryID = 47, SubcategoryID = null });
        LColObj.Add(new CollectionObject() { PersonID = 666, CategoryID = null, SubcategoryID = 424 });            

        return LColObj;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following would do, but you should be aware your way of storing data is quite odd.

(I mean, aren't all your subcategories related to a category ?)

```
// gets all the Ids of people of category 47
var personIds = entities
               .Where(x => x.categoryId == 47)
               .Select(x => x.PersonId)
               .Distinct()
               .ToList();
// gets all rows of people of category 47 and subcategory 424
var result = entities
            .Where(x => personIds.Contains(x.PersonId) && x.subCategoryId == 424)
            .ToList();
```

Linked [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZqKnCx).

Answer (score 0):

Well, while I was working on mine, it seems 3 other people came up with the same thing, so I'll throw in mine --- with the critical addition the OP needs....

```
Func<IGrouping<int, CollectionObject>, bool> query  = 
        gp=>
              gp.Any(g=>g.CategoryID == 47) && 
              gp.Any(g=>g.SubcategoryID == 424);

var q = (from p in ColObj
        group p by p.PersonID)
        .Where(query);
```

You'll need to replace  `query` with your one-field versions on occasion.